# How many CPU ticks does it take to store a single None?

Tags: rust

Look at this code:

```
type X = [u8; 256];
fn main() {
  let mut x : Option<X> = Some([0; 256]);
  x = None; // how many CPU ticks here?
  // x is used later
}
```

What do you think, how many ticks it will take to store `None` into `x`? Any ideas how to make the number smaller?

Comment: This depends on the CPU arch, I imagine. But assuming you're talking about amd64, have you tried to look at the generated assembly?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev what is your ballpark estimate? One, ten, hundred, thousand?

Comment: I thought you were looking for something slightly more accurate than a rando's guesstimate.

Comment: Random wild-assed guess: zero because the optimizer is probably able to optimize away all uses of `x` until you write a dynamic value to it… But like all performance-related questions, the only useful answer is to benchmark in your real use-case and environment.

Comment: Presumably one, since all you need to do is to flip one bit of the enum tag.

Comment: You could consider initializing x to None from the start, to avoid the cost of initializing and zeroing out the 256-byte array unnecessarily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**In short**: In this case, since `X` does not implement `Drop`, storing `None` is done in a single instruction. The number of CPU cycles depends heavily on the exact hardware and on caching effects. But assuming a modern x86-64 CPU and assuming the memory is in L1 cache (fair assumption for stack memory), it should only be a couple cycles.

---

To get meaningful assembly out of your program, I added two `black_box` calls to simulate using the value of your variable. I also made the value inside the array 13 as 0 is often treated in a special case.

```rust
let mut x : Option<X> = Some([13; 256]);
std::hint::black_box(&x);
x = None; // how many CPU ticks here?
std::hint::black_box(x);
```

Compiling that code in [the Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/MrPnxTWEh) gives the following assembly (commented by me):

```
.LCPI0_0:
    .zero   16,13    ; 16 bytes with value 13

example::foo:
    ; reserve space on the stack
    sub     rsp, 144      

    ; Copy the xmmword (16 bytes) from the constant location LCPI0_0 to the 
    ; register xmm0.
    movaps  xmm0, xmmword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_0]

    ; Copy the register xmm0 (now containing a bunch of 13s) to all these memory 
    ; locations (relative to the rsp register)
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 121], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 105], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 89], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 73], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 57], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 41], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 25], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp + 9], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 7], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 23], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 39], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 55], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 71], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 87], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 103], xmm0
    movups  xmmword ptr [rsp - 119], xmm0

    ; Move 1 to that single memory location
    mov     byte ptr [rsp - 120], 1

    ; Prepare parameters for black_box call -> ignore that
    lea     rax, [rsp - 120]
    mov     qword ptr [rsp - 128], rax
    lea     rcx, [rsp - 128]

    ; Write None to the variable  <--- LOOK HERE
    mov     byte ptr [rsp - 120], 0

    ; Prepare parameters for black_box call again -> ignore that
    mov     qword ptr [rsp - 128], rax

    ; Function outro: "clean" stack space and return from function
    add     rsp, 144
    ret
```

As you can see (assuming you trust my comments), storing a `None` here takes only one instruction, a `mov byte` one. This is one of the easiest instructions, but also one of the hardest to estimate the time of. Why? CPU-caching. Assuming the data is in L1 cache, this should be only a couple of CPU cycles. If the memory is not in any cache (unlikely for the stack), then it could take hundreds of cycles.

Also worth noting: this is so simple because the replaced data were just simple bytes and no cleanup was needed. If the `T` in `Option<T>` implements `Drop`, the drop function needs to be called at this point, making it a lot more complicated.

Why can this be done with only one byte stored you ask? Well, enums in Rust (which `Option` is) are generally stored like this:

```
┌─────┬─────────────┐  
│ tag │ contents... │  
└─────┴─────────────┘
```

The *tag*, or *discriminator*, just stores what variant of the enum (`None` or `Some`) is currently active. After that, the data area begins, where the data belonging to the active variant is stored.

Comment: Note that `mov byte ptr [rsp - 120], 1` could even take zero cycles due to out of order execution: the CPU may be able to reorder the instructions to insert that `mov` during a cycle when it would be otherwise stalled, meaning that the `mov` would effectively take no time at all.

Comment: Good point, though I wouldn't call it "zero cycles" then. But yeah, out of order execution is also certainly something to be aware of here.