# Why assigning None to a pointer takes different time for different types?

Tags: rust

This is my code:

```
use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};
use std::time::Instant;

const CAP : usize = 100000;

struct Foo<V> {
    head: *mut Option<V>
}

impl<V> Foo<V> {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let layout = Layout::array::<Option<V>>(CAP).unwrap();
            let ptr = alloc(layout);
            Self { head: ptr.cast() }
        }
    }
    pub fn measure(&self) {
        let start = Instant::now();
        for i in 0..CAP {
            unsafe {
                *self.head.add(i) = None;
            }
        }
        println!("spent: {:?}", start.elapsed());
    }
}

fn main() {
    Foo::<bool>::new().measure();
    Foo::<u64>::new().measure();
    Foo::<[u8; 100]>::new().measure();
    Foo::<[u8; 1000]>::new().measure();
}
```

It prints:

```
spent: 1.33425ms
spent: 1.654208ms
spent: 3.541ms
spent: 17.383459ms
```

Can you please explain why `:= None` takes different amount of time for different types, esp. taking into account [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154555/how-many-cpu-ticks-does-it-take-to-store-a-single-none)?

Comment: You need to pay attention to the answer that was given there: _"Assuming the data is in L1 cache, this should be only a couple of CPU cycles. If the memory is not in any cache [...], then it could take hundreds of cycles."_ As the overall size of the array increases, there are less guarantees that the memory written will be in L1 cache, and more guarantees that it may have to read more memory pages. Moreover, this benchmark is not meaningful, as it does not adequately prevent the main operation from being optimized out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's probably due to the difference in size between the types *and the effect that has on cache locality*. Assigning `None` takes the same time for all types, but before the computer can do it, it needs to bring the memory to the L1 cache.

Assuming that L1 cache lines are 16 bytes:

- `Option<bool>` takes up 1 byte, so bringing the first one to the L1 cache will also pull the next 15, so setting them will be effectively instantaneous (especially since the optimizer may decide to use SIMD instructions to set several of them in a single instruction).
- `Option<[u8; 100]>` takes up 101 bytes, so each one needs to be brought to the L1 cache individually.
- `Option<[u8; 1000]>` takes up 1001 bytes, so each one may need to be brought to the **L2** cache individually before it can even be brought into L1.

On modern computers, memory accesses are the bottleneck a lot more often than computing power.

Like I commented in your other question, the only way to answer performance-related questions is to measure *with a realistic usage pattern.*

Comment: This is true without optimizations (rustc 1.69) but even with opt-level=1 the compiler will not load the whole `Option`, but just set one of the bytes. The speed differences comes most likely from prefetching

Comment: @Unlikus I never said anything about loading the whole `Option`. Especially since it's not the compiler but the CPU doing the loading. But even fetching a single byte for each `Option` will cause a complete cache line to be fetched and so bring in the following values for `Option<bool>` but not for `Option<[u8;100]>` (since for the latter, the next value is more than a cache line away).

Comment: yes this is valid for `bool` vs `[u8;100]`, but not for the difference between `[u8;100]` and `[u8;1000]`

Comment: @Unlikus It's also valid for the difference between `[u8;100]` and `[u8;1000]`: the former fits in an L2 cache line while the latter doesn't.

Comment: The program will only load the 1 cache line which contains the enum variant information for both types. 1KB also fits comfortably in all somewhat modern L1d caches.

Answer (score 3):

I am pretty sure most of the time is spend with page faults, because the pages are first accessed when you write `None` to them. When you run `time` on Linux you see that most of the time is spend by the operation system, not your actual code.

The bigger the `Option<T>` the more page faults you get (per `Option`), it does not load the whole thing, it just writes to one of the bytes.

That's why you also will not observe a difference between
`Foo::<[u8;4098]>` and `Foo::<[u8;2*4098]>`, both will trigger one page fault per item. (On systems with 4KB pages)

Answer (score 1):

A similar and simpler code demonstrates the problem too:

```
use std::alloc::{alloc, Layout};
use std::time::Instant;
struct Foo {
    head: *mut u8
}
impl Foo {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        unsafe {
            let layout = Layout::array::<Option<u8>>(10000000).unwrap();
            let ptr = alloc(layout);
            Self { head: ptr }
        }
    }
    pub fn measure(&self, step: usize) {
        let start = Instant::now();
        for i in 0..10000 {
            unsafe {
                *self.head.add(i * step) = 0;
            }
        }
        println!("spent: {:?}", start.elapsed());
    }
}
fn main() {
    Foo::new().measure(1);
    Foo::new().measure(8);
    Foo::new().measure(100);
    Foo::new().measure(1000);
}
```

Thus, the answer posted above is right: it's the hardware problem.

Answer (score -1):

due to the difference in size between the types.

the 'bool' type is has a size of 1 byte and the smallest one. It takes the shortest amount of time to set to None.

The u64  a u64 has a size of 8 bytes.that type is larger and takes slightly longer,

and [u8; 100] is [u8; 100] has a size of 100 bytes. the largest and takes the longest.

Comment: I was told that opposite, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76154555/how-many-cpu-ticks-does-it-take-to-store-a-single-none